# Borderline/trickier cases of verbs needing the subjunctive mood?

Tags: subjunctives

The following  lists (scarcely)  verbs requiring the subjunctive mood (abbreviated as SM):  http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/subjunctive.html, http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000031.htm, https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-subjunctive.htm.

When manifested so openly, I can remember which verbs they are. Although I've already tried to consult https://english.stackexchange.com/q/145854/50720, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjunctive-mood (I read not everything here though), I still struggle with determining whether SM applies for the hazier unlisted, indefinite, undecided cases of verbs. Please advise on any tips or tricks?

For example, [[20% down the page] the subjunctive, another "mood", is used to express things like hopes, expectations, orders, hypothetical situations or something in the uncertain future](http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2014/09/johnson-grammar-0). Please advise on my question in full generality and not just this example:

> 1. Can you please confirm that nothing ? **be/is** ? revealed?

This is a hope, consistent with the Economist's definition above, so why does [it appear to fail?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confirm+that+nothing+be%2Cconfirm+that+nothing+is&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconfirm%20that%20nothing%20is%3B%2Cc0) (Ngrams contradicts Google search? Google did return some, albeit few, results for [be](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%22confirm+that+nothing+be%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=bOVpVMuAPdKC9AW56ICABA))

Comment: It is important that questions be clear.

Comment: I think the questions are "Please advise on any tips or tricks?" and "Please advise on my question in full generality and not just this example"

Comment: Your Economist columnist spends a lot of time wittering on about a distinction which is more about ***insist*** having the two senses ***maintain** [that some claimed fact **is** true, in the face of opposition]* and ***require** [that some condition **be** met]*. Trying to use the subjunctive to disambiguate there is a bit pointless, given how many native speakers today no longer demand that subjunctive ***is*** used wherever it could be [sometimes, *could have been*] valid.

Answer (score 3):

You need to know that in British English no verbs *require* the subjunctive. "Most subjunctive structures are formal and unusual in British English" (Michael Swan, *Practical English Usage*, 2005.568). The tip therefore in this variety of English is not to use the subjunctive.

The sentence asked about, "*1. Can you please confirm that nothing ? be/is ? revealed?*" is a request for confirmation of a fact, not an expression of hope. The subjunctive would not appropriate there even for those people who use subjunctive forms. The verb required is indicative 'is'.

Comment: Indeed, lexically there is no distinction between the bare infinitive and the subjunctive; [POS taggers can't distinguish between them](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/claws7tags.html). Pirate speech uses it, though.

Comment: There is no difference in the form of the bare infinitive in the *present* subjunctive.

Comment: I think OP's "confirm" example is trying to shoehorn in a subjunctive to convey the sense of *confirm that nothing **will be** revealed* (by some process that hasn't finished yet, or at least for which the outcome hasn't yet been determined). Which could also be expressed by *confirm that nothing **is to be** revealed*. Compare *"I demand [that] he be released"*, and the (iffy, imho) possibility of [*I demand that he **is to be** treated well*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22demand+that+he+is+to+be+slotted%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can you please confirm that nothing ? be/is ? revealed?

One can confirm that one understands that nothing is to be revealed.

One can confirm that nothing is (being) revealed.

One can confirm that nothing has been revealed.

But one cannot *confirm* that nothing *be* revealed.  This form of the sentence is nonsensical: an *injunction* is not a statement about the world but a statement about a desired world and is thus incapable of being confirmed.